# colored points in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a table with 3 numeric columnes. Two of them are coordinates and the third one means color. There are hundreds of rows in my text file.
I want to make a picture, where to first numbers mean coordinates of each point and the third one is the color of the point. The bigger number - the darker point.
How could i do this?
The example of the row in my file:

```
99.421875   48.921875   0.000362286050144
```

Comment: What exactly are you plotting again? I find it unclear still.

Comment: I want to make a point plot, where first column in my file is X, second is Y and the third one is color of the point. When the third number is small the point should be lighter, and when it is big the point is dark red for example

Comment: Are you looking for a base solution or is `ggplot2` okay as well?

Comment: It's no matter, I need only a picture :)

Comment: Which the minimum and the maximum value of the third column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do?

```
require(ggplot2)
# assuming your data is in df and x,y, and col are the column names.
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
           geom_point(colour="red", size = 3, aes(alpha=col))

# sample data

set.seed(45) 
df <- data.frame(x=runif(100)*sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), 
                 y= runif(100*sample(1:50, 100, replace=T)), 
                 col=runif(100/sample(1:100)))
```

Plot:

[image: ggplot2_alpha]

Answer (score 0):

A `lattice` solution:

```
library(lattice)
mydata <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1,1,1,2,5,10),nrow=3)
xyplot(mydata[,2] ~ mydata[,1], col = mydata[,3], pch= 19 , 
                           alpha = (mydata[,3]/10), cex = 15)
```

`alpha` here controls the transparency.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution:

```
##Generate data
##Here z lies between 0 and 10
dd = data.frame(x = runif(100), y= runif(100), z= runif(100, 0, 10))
```

First normalise z:

```
dd$z = dd$z- min(dd$z)
dd$z = dd$z/max(dd$z)
```

Then plot as normal using the size of z for the shading:

```
##See ?gray for other colour combinations
##pch=19 gives solid points. See ?point for other shapes 
plot(dd$x, dd$y, col=gray(dd$z), pch=19)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using base... to change the colour, you can replace some of data[,3] to 0 inside the `rgb()`

```
n <- 1000
data <- data.frame(x=runif(n),y=runif(n),col=runif(n))
plot(data[,1:2],col=rgb(data[,3],data[,3],data[,3],maxColorValue = max(data[,3])),pch=20)
```